# Appmaker: App does not saves record to database?

Tags: javascript, save, google-app-maker

I have a form which used to work, but today I noticed it does not save the created record to the database.

I can access the newly created record from the other parts of the app, so it must be stored somewhere, when I access the database from MySQGL Workbench, the record is not there, also If I reload the app the record is gone.

I run some code on the Send button:

```js
widget.datasource.createItem({success: function() {
  widget.parent.descendants.errorLabel.text = 
    "Sikeres mentés! ";
  setTimeout(function(){ widget.parent.descendants.errorLabel.text = 
    "";},10000);
}, 
failure: function(error) {
  widget.parent.descendants.errorLabel.text = 
    "Sikertelen mentés, talán már létezik ilyen cég? ";
  setTimeout(function(){ widget.parent.descendants.errorLabel.text = 
    "";},10000);
}
});
```

Which tells me that the creating of the item is succesful. When it used to work it took some time to create it, but now it just responds immediately that the save is succesful.

Also the other forms in the app can save records without trouble.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure, but you did not by chance change the datasource to 'manual save'? The is the only thing that would come to mind of the top of my head that would result in this type of behavior.

Comment: Actually I did!! I did not mention it because it has not caused any trouble on my other forms. I understood, that using the createItem() function I could save a record, even in manual save mode, but I must have misinterpreted something.

Comment: What you will need to do then is just call `widget.datasource.createItem()` in one line of code and then do `widget.datasource.saveChanges()` and incorporate your success and failure function inside the saveChanges().